# put jpg data from xmlhttprequest into <img /> tag

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jpeg, httpresponse, binary-data

here is some part of my code

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
document.imglive.innerHTML = '<img src="data:image/jpeg,' + xmlhttp.responseText + '"/>';
```

that don´t seem to work.
i also tried

```
document.imglive.src= xmlhttp.responseText;
```

that neither worked

I checked some of the asked questions here but none of the answers where helping at this porblem.

Comment: what does `responseText` contain?

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `document.imglive.src='/new/src.jpg';`?

Comment: @Joseph some jpeg data like �����JFIF���������...�*C���NC�]���,O��QE�

Comment: Aside from the reason, the `document.imglive.src = "data:image/jpeg,..."` should be in the `onreadystatechange`-handler.

Comment: @paulslater i am reading also the header data out of the xmlhttpresponse object if i would make a second request the data may have changed. i need header data and content from one request.

Comment: @Gobliins what i meant was what encoding is it?

Comment: i guess it should be a raw (not sure about that) jpg data stream with no base64 encoding

Comment: @Gobliins : could you provide a working fiddle or whole code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use base64 for these things. In modern browsers there's this `btoa` native function that may help you:

```
document.imglive.innerHTML = "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," + btoa(xmlhttp.responseText) + "'/>";
```

For other browsers there are simple emulated implementations, just check them out.

P.S.: don't pollute the `document` object, use a separate variable or a namespace.

Comment: _don't pollute the `document` object_ - I would bet that there is an `<img id="imglive" />` tag (or a div or anything else with that id)

Comment: Eh, forgot about that possibility. That's because I don't consider it a good practice.

Comment: i tried the btoa, atob functions, when i use them i get an error about invalid character in the string

Comment: Uhm, that's probably because `responseText` is encoded in UTF8, and some characters go over the 0-255 range, so an ecception is raised. That's also why isn't a good idea to load images like that... Unless the source file isn't already base64-encoded.

Comment: @Hugolpz A working fiddle would need the picture to be loaded on the fiddle hosting site, so no. Anyway, it's pretty much that, just one line of code: do you really need a fiddle for that? Or maybe you need some examples on AJAX requests?

Comment: @MaxArt http://jsfiddle.net/Ft9d3/2/ there is were I got locked when implementing your code.

Comment: just fyi, the answer I posted below should handle mime types / encoding for you (unless you have a real error in your xhr request)

Note that you appear to be pointing to a png but this answer explicitly sets mime type to jpeg.  This is no good, and you should let the system figure this out for you (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with IE10+, you can use `xhr.responseType = 'blob'` in conjunction with `window.URL.createObjectURL()` (to get free support for getting the correct mime type).

```
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(response) {
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
  document.imglive.src = url; // from your example code
}
xhr.open("GET", theUrl, true);
```