# How does one use POST with XMLHttpRequest to send JPEG file to server?

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I have an IMG tag such as this:

```
<img src="test.jpeg" className="Test" alt="Test" height="42" width="42">
```

but I had to send test.jpeg over xmlHttpRequest to a web site, how would it be done 
using XmlHttpRequest(). A [related question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687427/put-jpg-data-from-xmlhttprequest-into-img-tag) but it uses a GET, to populate the DOM. The problem is to use POST, with XMLHttpRequest, to send the "test.jpeg" file.

Answer (score 2):

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("inp", document.getElementById("inp").files[0]);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://yourdomain.com/submit.php");
request.send(formData);
```

your html code:

```
<input id="inp" type='file'>
```

Comment: I used something like this in react but, it did not work, as files[0] object was being passed a null object. In other words in react, the object passed was a null, by way of getElementById(),  I am using react, not PHP so its a little different.

Answer (score 0):

you could send your image base64 encoded

```
function readFile() {

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

    var FR= new FileReader();

    FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("b64").value     = e.target.result;
    }); 

    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }

}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

the image encode will be add as value in #b64 hidden input

```
<input id="inp" type='file'>
<input id="b64" type='hidden' name='b64'>
```

btw, you can trigger the readFile to submit event, be sure to select the input file properly.

if your server is PHP use this function to save the image:

```
function save_image($base64_string, $image_location) {

    $ifp = fopen( $image_location, 'wb' ); 
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );
    fclose( $ifp ); 

    return $image_location; 
}

save_image($_POST['b64'], '/you/location');
```

Comment: Is another solution possibly that is as follows: to use toDataURL(), ie, load image onto a canvas and then convert it to data using toDataURL, which in turn could be sent over XMLHttpRequest, as raw data?

Comment: you could use the formData object, I will add an answer.

Comment: Just for info, is there a way to encode a jpeg image into XMLHttpRequest formattable code that can be  send over XMLHttpRequest, easily, one can use toDataURL(), to convert an image to data, ad then append to a file, is that that a correct way to do image file data transmission?